# The coordinates of the target range are outside the dimensions of the sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use this code and while in the past it worked well, today I received this error message:

> The coordinates of the target range are outside the dimensions of the sheet. (line 27, ___.gs)

My code is not too complex:

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheetNameToWatch1 = "Assign_Page";
  var columnNumberToWatch = 19;
  var valueToWatch = "Delivred";
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "K_Delivery_Archive";
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo2 = "Buffering";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch1 && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, 22).copyTo(targetRange, {contentsOnly: true});

    var targetSheet2 = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo2); 
    var targetRange2 = targetSheet2.getRange(targetSheet2.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, 22).copyTo(targetRange2, {contentsOnly: true});

    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow()); // line 27

    var Sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Clients_Page");
    var Sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Assign_Page");
    var Sheet3 = ss.getSheetByName("Report");
    var Sheet4 = ss.getSheetByName("Delivery_Information");
    Sheet4.showSheet();
    Sheet1.hideSheet();
    Sheet2.hideSheet();
    Sheet3.hideSheet();
  }
}
```

What causes this error, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid." error when using lastRow as range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41557017/the-coordinates-or-dimensions-of-the-range-are-invalid-error-when-using-lastr)

Answer (score 1):

It's very likely that the problem is due to

```
targetSheet2.getLastRow()+ 1
```

The proper solution will depend on several factors that are not mentioned by the OP, but here is a hint:

If the sheet has open ended formulas that return `""` then the last row is the same as the maximum number of rows in the sheet and inserting more rows will not solve the problem.

Comment: line 27 in the original code was the call to `deleteRow`. If this is anything like https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68062620 though, then the previous `getRange` call is the one that has an issue, i.e. the copying to `targetRange2`.

Comment: @tehhowch The code I mentioned is used to set `targetRange2` :)